# How to return from a function?

Tags: c++

I have declared a string variable in the header file:

File.h

```
#include <string>
class Declare{
  public:
     string match(string word, string user_input);
};
```

File.cpp

```
#include File.h
#include <string>

string Declare::match(string word, string user_input){
    if(word == user_input){
        return "return";
   }
};
```

I am getting an error saying

> E0147 declaration is incompatible with "<error-type> Declare::match(<error-type> word, <error-type> user_input)" (declared at line 12 of "C:\Users\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\File.h") ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\File.cpp

How to fix this?

Comment: Is your function supposed to return a `string` or a boolean?

Comment: What if your test yields `word != user_input`? What should the function `return` then? Also, your function return type is `string`, but you seem to return a `bool`...

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I want to return string

Comment: @IshkMagar _"I want to return string"_ That doesn't make much sense. Can you please [edit] your question, and show us how you plan to use that function?

Comment: @IshkMagar What string do you want to return if `word` is not equivalent to `user_input`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I am not doing error checking if word isn't equivalent to user_input

Comment: @IshkMagar exactly, which makes the return value *indeterminate* when they are not equivilent.  If you declare a return type, you must specify a `return` statement on every possible code path that causes the function to exit.  A function with a return type must `return` *something*.

Comment: @IshkMagar _`return "return";`_ What should that mean for the caller? I still don't see how that should make any sense. What should be returned if the strings don't match?

Comment: In your case the warning should be something like `control reaches end of non void function`, that means that if the strings don't mach function returns nothing, which leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: @IshkMagar Can you please do as I've asked for: How do you want to use that function? What is the context / use case you want to solve with it. [Edit] again please!

Comment: @IshkMagar You *are* checking if `word` is equivalent to `user_input`. You just haven't told the compiler what you want it to return if they aren't equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

> I have declared a string variable in Header file

No, you have declared a class that has a method that returns a `string`.  BIG difference than simply declaring a `string` variable.

> I am getting an error saying "declaration is incompatible"

Your `match()` method is declared as returning a `string`, but it is trying to `return` a `bool` instead.  And, the return value is *indeterminate* if `word` and `user_input` do not actually match, since you don't `return` *any* value in that situation.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <string>

class Declare{
  public:
     bool match(std::string word, std::string user_input);
};
```

```cpp
#include "File.h"

bool Declare::match(std::string word, std::string user_input){
    return (word == user_input);
};
```

---

If you really want to return a `string` (which does not make sense to do in your example), you need to handle the case when `operator==` returns false so you can `return` a different value, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>

class Declare{
  public:
     std::string match(std::string word, std::string user_input);
};
```

```
#include "File.h"

std::string Declare::match(std::string word, std::string user_input){
    if (word == user_input){
        return "true";
    } else {
        return "false";
    }
};
```

Comment: What if I want to return string ( return "return" instead of return true)

Comment: Then change the return type back to `string`, put back your original `if` statement, and then add an `else` block to it to `return` a different value when the two strings are mismatched.

Comment: error-type is the error showing on "match()"

Comment: @IshkMagar You are going to have to be more specific than that. What is the *complete* **copy/pasted** error message? Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the error in action.

Comment: I just edit the question

Comment: @IshkMagar what you edited makes no sense whatsoever. "*declaration is incompatible or error-type is the error showing on "match()"*" does not look like something a compiler would say.  Please **copy/paste** exactly what the compiler says, verbatim.

Comment: @IshkMagar not far from the Error List you should find the Output tab. In the Output tab you'll find the complete build output in text. The Error List's job is to present an overview of the errors and to keep the overview simple and pretty it leaves out a lot of information. Often you'll find the information that was left out is exactly what you needed in order to understand and fix the mistake. If the  Error List leaves you with questions, switch to Output. Plus the Output's text pastes nicely into a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @IshkMagar `<error-type> Declare::match(<error-type> word, <error-type> user_input)`, seems the compiler doesn't know what `string` is in your code. The code in your original question was using `string`, but πάνταῥεῖ changed your question to use `std::string` after I posted my answer showing `std::string` (I have now reverted that change). If you are not using `std::string` in your actual project, you should be. `string` will not work unless you have a `using namespace std;` or `using std::string;` statement in your Header file (neither of which you should be using in a Header file)